# Kernal logestic regression

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression

I am trying to understand how to apply the kernelize the logistic regression is there a step by step tutorial with simple math to do so

Comment: What do you mean by apply? Do you want people to recommend you packages to use or you want to implement it yourself? I am guessing the latter since you asked for the mathematics, but I can't be sure.